# .Net Core Connected Services - Sharing Types

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

With a .Net Framework project, you used to be able to share types from common WCF services by adding any additional services to the Reference.svcmap file as follows:

[image: add metadata source]

Source:
https://github.com/geersch/WcfSvcMap

Now, with .net core, we have connected services, and all we get is a `ConnectedService.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.30311.775",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "http://hostname/appname/ExampleService.svc"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, ExampleService"
    ],
    "targetFramework": "netstandard2.0",
    "typeReuseMode": "None"
  }
}
```

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Does anyone know how to do the same with the connectedservice.json?

Note, the types are built from WSDL entirely, there are no referenced assemblies from which to share types.
The option to '**Reuse types in referenced assemblies**' has no impact here.

Comment: Did you find a way to avoid manually updating generated classes after each api update ?

Comment: No, fortunately the API's I'm calling haven't changed since I asked the question.  I ended up creating a wrapper class that mapped the common types to something my app controlled.